# Java - Color Rectangle

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int height = getHeight();
        int width = getWidth();
        g.drawRect(350, 510, 110, 170);
        g.drawRect(470, 510, 110, 170);
        g.drawRect(590, 510, 110, 170);
        g.drawRect(710, 510, 110, 170);
        g.drawRect(830, 510, 110, 170);
        g.drawRect(350, 30, 110, 170);
        g.drawRect(470, 30, 110, 170);
        g.drawRect(590, 30, 110, 170);
        g.drawRect(710, 30, 110, 170);
        g.drawRect(830, 30, 110, 170);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(110, 450, 110, 170);
        g.drawRect(110, 60, 110, 170);
    }
}
```

I need to color red every Rectangle ( i mean inside the Rectangle ), but with this g.setColor ( Color.RED ) ; i can only color the exterior part of Rectanlge

Comment: Use g.fillRect() Luke

Comment: I think you should have looked around on google for an answer to this-- try 'fill rectangle java.awt'-- there are several answers that come up and go into more detail that can keep helping you. Making a new question here is probably best left for once you've failed to find something on google.

Comment: Thnks guys. I found !! And what about if i want to have the half rectangle blue and the rest red? What should i do then ?

Comment: Spend some time and actually think about your problem. You already know how to do everything you need.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`drawRect()` from the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

> Draws the outline of the specified rectangle. The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x + width. The top and bottom edges are at y and y + height. The rectangle is drawn using the graphics context's current color.

That's why you need to use [`fillRect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29):

> Fills the specified rectangle. The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x + width - 1. The top and bottom edges are at y and y + height - 1. The resulting rectangle covers an area width pixels wide by height pixels tall. The rectangle is filled using the graphics context's current color.

From your last comment: `And what about if i want to have the half rectangle blue and the rest red? What should i do then ?`

Draw 2 rectangles, one ends where the other one starts, something like:

```
g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.fillRect(100, 50, 50, 50);
```

I haven't tested the above code, but you get the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

`g.drawRect()` only draws rectangle's border. You probably should use `g.fillRect()` which fills your rectangle with solid color. [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fillRect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect-int-int-int-int-) to fill a rectangular area rather than just drawing a rectangle.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
g.fillRect(x, y, width, height)
```

Description [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)!